# terraform cli does not accept aws credentials

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I am trying to create ec2 instance using terraform. Passing credentials through terraform cli fails, while hardcoding it in main.tf works fine

This is to create ec2 instance dynamically using terraform

terraform apply works with following main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-west-2"
  access_key = "hard-coded-access-key"
  secret_key = "hard-coded-secret-key"
}
resource "aws_instance" "ec2-instance" {
  ami = "ami-id"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  tags {
    Name = "test-inst"
   }
}
```

while the following does not work:

```
terraform apply -var access_key="hard-coded-access-key" -var secret_key="hard-coded-secret-key"
```

Is there any difference in the above two ways of running the commands? As per terraform documentation both of the above should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `terraform` module can use input variables, including the main module. But before using input variables, you must declare them.

Create a `variables.tf` file on the same folder you have your `main.tf` file:

```
variable "credentials" {
  type = object({
    access_key = string
    secret_key = string
  })

  description = "My AWS credentials"
}
```

Then you can reference input variables in your code like that:

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-west-2"
  access_key = var.credentials.access_key
  secret_key = var.credentials.secret_key
}
```

And you can either run:

`terraform apply -var credentials.access_key="hard-coded-access-key" -var credentials.secret_key="hard-coded-secret-key"`

Or you could create a `terraform.tfvars` file with the following content:

```
# ------------------
# AWS Credentials
# ------------------
credentials= {
  access_key = "hard-coded-access-key"
  secret_key = "hard-coded-secret-key"
}
```

And then simply run `terraform apply`.

But the key point is that you must declare input variables before using them.

Answer (score 0):

The @Felipe answer is right, But I will never recommend defining Access key and secret key in variables.tf, What you have to to do is to left it blinks and set keys using `aws configure` or  other options is to create keys for terraform deployment purpose only using `aws configure --profile terraform` or without profile `aws configur`

so your connection.tf or main.tf will look like this,

```
provider "aws" {
  #You can use an AWS credentials file to specify your credentials.
  #The default location is $HOME/.aws/credentials on Linux and OS X, or "%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials" for Windows users
  region              = "us-west-2"
# profile configured during aws configure --profile
  profile             = "terraform"
# you can also restrict account here, to allow particular account for deployment
  allowed_account_ids = ["12*****45"]
}
```

You can also tell separate file for secret key and access key, The reason behind this is, as Variables.tf is part of your configuration language or bitbucket, so it's better to not place these sensitive keys in variables.tf

You can create a file somewhere in your system and give the path of the keys in the provider section.

```
provider "aws" {
  region              = "us-west-2"
  shared_credentials_file = "$HOME/secret/credentials"
}
```

Here is the format of the credentials file

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = A*******Z
aws_secret_access_key = A*******/***xyz
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however, I am using this in conjunction with teamcity, so I am going to store credentials in teamcity environment variable and pass the environment variable to terraform files. I have not tried this yet, but that would be the next step once I get the variables working using variables file.

Comment: sound good, you can go with the above answer the only thing that I would recommend is to use `${var.credentials.access_key}` interpolation in this way.